# Is it okay to initialize a pointer to "point" at NULL first than make it point at an array later?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a struct with a value and a reference to another struct of that type.

`struct mystruct { int val; mystruct* next; };`

And then I have initialized a pointer like `struct mystruct* ptr=NULL;`. This pointer is supposed to point at an array of structs later. I believe it would be much smarter to do the malloc(sizeof(struct));
and free(struct);later. But it seems to work anyway but it doesn't seem right. I want to change it and I can hardly explain to myself why. Any assumptions?

Comment: Yes it is OK, but better to post your sample code to add clarity to your question.

Comment: Post your try/exemple of code as the man stated above . But from what you wrote it's wrong to do `free(struct);` as struct is not the pointer , you need to free the pointer using `free(ptr);`

Comment: It's like being in the in the jewelry shop with your girlfriend: You can point at anything (including nothing), and you can re-decide on what you're pointing at at any time. Only when you're actually up for grabs on the thing you point at, you need to be very careful considering the possible outcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is “okay” to give any object an initial value and to set it to another value later. However, everything is dependent on the situation. Giving an object an initial value that is not intended to be used is a method of guarding problems caused by a bug in which the value of the object is used before it is given a desired value. Some objects can be initialized to a value that, although not the desired value, will likely cause less harm than leaving the object uninitialized.

For a pointer, a null pointer is often such a value: In many systems, attempting to dereference a null pointer will cause the program to trap. This will reveal the error and prevent the program from doing other erroneous things, which may be considered a better result than alternatives, which could include the program continuing execution and producing incorrect results or writing incorrect results to storage, possibly erasing good data. Whether this solution of guarding against bugs is worth the cost depends on the situation.

If safety is important, but not critical, giving an object an initial value that will minimize harm is a reasonable guard against worse program misbehavior.

If safety is critical, an object should be initialized with a known-good value or it should be proven that the object will be given a good value before it is used.

If performance is critical and safety is not so important, an object may be left uninitialized until it is given a value.

If you are doing this in a learning exercise or other student project, then practice both methods and see which is more useful to you. Are your programs easier to debug if they crash as soon as a pointer initialized to `NULL` is used or if they continue executing for a while before an uninitialized pointer causes some other problem?

Comment: That sounds reasonable as it sounds interesting. I am actually coding this for a friend and it is experimental. Safety could be an issue in the future. So I will do it like this:
I test if there is enough memory, set the pointer on NULL, and as soon as the arrays, which are quite large, are initialized, I will let them point at the first index of the first array.

But thank you very much for you advice and your time. I hope you enjoy the rest of this wonderful Saturday!